# In Android, why shouldn't one put Bitmaps in the Application class?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

This question only pertains to the development of Android applications.

When the orientation of the screen is changed, the Activity restarts, but not the Application. As a result, Bitmaps often must be re-instantiated.

But by putting the Bitmaps in a class that extends Application, those Bitmaps won't be re-instantiated.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    Bitmap bmp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(),R.drawable.bmp);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't that make the Application more efficient? However, I have not seen anyone do anything like this, so I deduct that there is probably a downside to this.

So, getting to the question, why shouldn't I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android you usually have a very limited memory(because of old devices) so keeping Bitmaps(might have a huge size) in memory is a very risky decision. Also, it's better to resize bitmaps so they take only the necessary memory, and the scale may change if the orientation does.

Comment: Well put, not to mention the bitmaps should be related to the activity, fragment, or view using them, not the whole application. There is a special way to save one large item during a configuration change (i forget the method name) but it has been deprecated for using what is dubbed a "data" fragment